# In Android Studio, How to change the color of Month and Year in a CalendarView?

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, calendar, calendarview

I'm trying to modify the colors of a CalendarView on my Android native app.

I found some answers and I was able to modify the color of the numbers and week's days. However, I can't find the way to change the color of the month and the year in the header of the Calendar (I need to change these to White):

[image: Current preview of my calendar]

To change the colors of days and week, I used the following code in the activity:

```
    <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarViewRealizarReserva"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.CalendarView.Custom"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewDateCustomText"
    android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewRealizarReserva" />
```

And I edited the Style file adding the following code:

```
<style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
<style name="CalenderViewDateCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:weekNumberColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:headerYearTextAppearance">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
<style name="CalenderViewWeekCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Do you have an idea to modify the color of the Month and Year?

Comment: Use theme for Calenderview

Comment: @Venky could you please provide me some reference about the utilization of theme for CalendarView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The item android:textColorPrimary is the right one.

```
<style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thank the lord!  why is this so hard!